# Adding indicator icons to viewed pages in android app

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to add an icon page indicator to my fragments and I get stopped working error?could someone also help me about how to put icons in my indicator?I can add circle page indicator but icon page indicator gives me "has stopped working" error.
here's my .java code

```
public class Levels extends FragmentActivity {
    IconPageIndicator mIndicator;
    Button startgamebtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.levels);

        float pixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                500, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        ViewPager viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        viewpager.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (height*3)/4;
        viewpager.setAdapter(new myAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        mIndicator = (IconPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.Title);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(viewpager);

        final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

    }
}

class myAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public myAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int id) {
        Fragment fr = null;

        if (id == 0)
            fr = new LevelA();

        if (id == 1)
            fr = new LevelB();

        if (id == 2)
            fr = new LevelC();

        if (id == 3)
            fr = new LevelD();

        return fr;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 4;
    }

}
```

and here is my .xml code

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <com.viewpagerindicator.IconPageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/Title"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
           android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please post the error log from LogCat?

Comment: @TofferJ it says : java.lang.RuntimeException:Unable to start activity componentInfo and java.lang.ClassCastException:com.example.who.myAdapter cannot be cast to com.viewpagerindicator.IconPagerAdapter

Comment: The error message states that the adapter you use when viewpager.setAdapter() Should be a IconPagerAdapter try to change the myAdapter class to extend/implement IconPagerAdapter instead.